# Does Flow support SP site column lookups?

Tags: sharepoint-online, updatelistitems, flow

I was thinking of using Flow in SharePoint to update a list item, seemed simple enough. Then I noticed none of my lookups were showing.

Hmmm, my lookups are driven by site columns, could that be the problem? Made a test lookup in the list NOT adding from existing site columns. Voila, it shows up in Flow: Update Item.

So, am I approaching this wrong or does MS Flow for SP really not support site column lookups? If so, can I use the Send an HTTP Request action to update an item that has site column lookups?

Please share any experiences or solutions if you've encountered this.

**UPDATE**

Its worse then I thought. Site column lookup values also aren't available from Dynamic Content: When an item is created. Ouch. Now what?

Answer (score 0):

Per my test, we can update site column lookups in the flow. As you can see, we can choose the  value from the drop down list. Note: if you enter the value manually, you must enter the lookup id instead of lookup value.

[image]